# Error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#

I keep getting this error when i try to access forms that calls WCF functions.
Actually it works on my local machine but when it is in the server, this things happens :(

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.]
 System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6115603
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout) +48

 [MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.]
 System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +9439503
 System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +345
 Project.WCFUser.Users.HaveAccess(String userid, String filename) +0
 Project.WCFUser.Users.HaveAccess(String userid, String filename) in C:\Documents and Settings\MyPC\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Project\Project\Project\Service References\Users\Reference.cs:71
 Project.View.User.Details.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\MyPC\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Project\Project\Project\View\User\Details.aspx.cs:50
System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
 System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

Comment: Which binding are you using? Could you post the security configuration for WCF service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error was solved by changing my security settings inside the web.config

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
       realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```